# Are PostgreSQL functions atomic? (ID generation)

Tags: postgresql, sequence, auto-increment

Let' say I have the following Stored Procedure in PostgreSQL. (Please note that this is not real code. I know this can be done in another and better way, it is just an example to illustrate my question)

```
CREATE FUNCTION testFunction( ) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE iNewID integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT CurrentID INTO iNewID FROM TestTable; // statement 1

  iNewID := iNewID + 1;

  UPDATE TestTable SET CurrentID=iNewID;  // statement 2

  RETURN iNewID;
END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Let's say that two different users run this at almost the same time. Can they get the same ID returned?

I will try to explain in other words. In the code I have commented two statements. If two users run this at the same time. In what order is the statement called. Can I be sure it will be like this:

- User A Statement 1
- User A Statement 2
- User B Statement 1
- User B Statement 2

Or could it be like this (resulting in same ID):

- User A Statement 1
- User B Statement 1
- User A Statement 2
- User B Statement 2

I hope you understand my question. I have really tried to search the net for an answer to this, but with no luck. This could be because I don't have any name for this? What is it called?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 3):

> Let's say that two different users run this at almost the same time. Can they get the same ID returned?

Yes, of course. It's just the same as if you ran it as two separate statements outside a transaction, doing the addition in your app.

[I wrote about this recently](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-read-modify-write-cycles/).

Use a [`SEQUENCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) to ensure unique IDs. The [`SERIAL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) pseudo-type makes this easier. Note that the IDs aren't guaranteed to be gapless; it's normal to have IDs like: 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 14, .. if transactions roll back, the server is restarted, etc.

If that's a problem for you, you'll want to instead do:

```
SELECT CurrentID INTO iNewID FROM TestTable FOR UPDATE;
... blah blah ...
```

... which will lock the row so other transactions can't update it until the current one commits or rolls back. That can actually be simplified using PostgreSQL-specific features into:

```
  UPDATE TestTable
  SET CurrentID = iNewID
  RETURNING CurrentID;
```

which you can then wrap in an SQL function or run in PL/PgSQL with `RETURN QUERY`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and link to great article!... I just used the ID example to illustrate my problem. This is not what I try to do in my real work. For my real work it is not possible to edit SQL or use 'FOR UPDATE'. Maybe I has to look into SERIALIZABLE transactions mentioned in your article. What I don't like about that though is that the second session is aborted. Is it not possible for a stored procedure to work in the same way as a single statement. So if two sessions starts at the same time one of them waits for the other to complete and then run?